# Change color of line dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-animation

I have a line drawn using `Canvas`. Let's name the two endpoints as A and B. I also have a point. I moved it from point A to point B using `TranslateAnimation`. Now, what I want is, to change color of the line as the point moves. I can surely change color of the line as a whole. But how to color it according to the movement of the point? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure you can, but you could use a `GradientDrawable` instead (in the shape of a narrow rectangle). You'd then have set-able colors at each end and a means of adjusting the gradient center as the end points move (`setGradientCenter`).

Comment: Let's name your moving point C. Why not draw two lines, AC and CB, and color them according to what you actually want?